# c++ Is there any windows API for listing device drivers shown in the windows driver manager console?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, drivers

I want to list device drivers as shown in the device drivers(devmgmt.msc) window.
`SetupDiGetClassDevs()` API provides basic informations about the device. But I need more information like driver install date, driver Signer.

Comment: WMI - you can access it with `wmic` or powershell `Get-WMIObject`

Comment: Yes, I have tried `win32_pnpsigneddriver`wmi class. But it is not providing information such as `ProblemCode` and most of the time `installDate` returns null. So, is there any other class or any other API available for retrieving driver details

Comment: That is a completely different question. "What WMI class can I use to find out..." whatever it is you want to know. What do you actually want to know? Driver signer is there. What do you mean by "Install date" - what are you going to use it for?

Comment: *"I need more information like [...]"* - That's not a useful statement. We cannot guess what you need. You need to tell us.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/retrieving-the-status-and-problem-code-for-a-device-instance

Comment: you can try this [Detailed PCI-E information, Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47854075/2521214) to obtain specific details about HW ... just querry the stuff you want (in table you got listing of possible options) however I see no driver info (does not mean it is not hidden there somwhere)

Answer (score 0):

You can interrogate just about every aspect of the system configuration or running state using WMI - Windows Management Instrumentation.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389273(v=vs.85).aspx

There is a command-line tool, `wmic`, which will do this, and also a PowerShell cmdlet, `Get-WmiObject`.

E.g. to list devices:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class CIM_LogicalDevice
```

Accessing WMI from C++:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389762(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The second link is broken. Active page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/creating-a-wmi-application-using-c-