# uint64_t in glsl is not supported with Nvidia/AMD?

Tags: c, opengl, graphics, glsl

I am using a GTX 1050 on a laptop, lastest NVidia driver 417, and using OpenGL glad with the spec

```
Language/Generator: C/C++
Specification: gl
APIs: gl=4.5
Profile: core
Extensions:
    GL_ARB_bindless_texture,
    GL_ARB_gpu_shader_int64
Loader: True
Local files: False
Omit khrplatform: False
Reproducible: False
```

it compile but when glsl is running it fail. I have try with all the add-on for glad, still compile but no shader.

It's with Nuklear GUI where in the creation part the is this shader :

```
static const GLchar *fragment_shader =
        NK_SHADER_VERSION
        NK_SHADER_BINDLESS
        NK_SHADER_64BIT
        "precision mediump float;\n"
        "uniform uint64_t Texture;\n"
        "in vec2 Frag_UV;\n"
        "in vec4 Frag_Color;\n"
        "out vec4 Out_Color;\n"
        "void main(){\n"
        "   sampler2D smp = sampler2D(Texture);\n"
        "   Out_Color = Frag_Color * texture(smp, Frag_UV.st);\n"
        "}\n";
```

with the define :

```
#define NK_SHADER_VERSION "#version 450 core\n"
#define NK_SHADER_BINDLESS "#extension GL_ARB_bindless_texture : require\n"
#define NK_SHADER_64BIT "#extension GL_ARB_gpu_shader_int64 : require\n"
```

the error output is **'GL_ARB_gpu_shader_int64' is not supported**

I don't know why ? it's been tested on a AMD same error.

Comment: Maybe it's because that extension is not supported on your hardware?

Comment: did look with a application, GL_ARB_gpu_shader_int64 is enable on the CG

Comment: @Cewein you need to check the extension string for the `GL_ARB_gpu_shader_int64` if you enable it in code that does not mean your driver and gfx card support it ... see [Determine Intel HD Graphics Card Version Via WinAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35826975/2521214) on how to obtain the string. There are also apps for that I think OpenGL extension viewer do it... As you can see in the link mine GeForce GTX 550 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 do not have that extension either (GL 4.5.0)...