# How can I make OpenGL and GDI both working properly at the same time?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, opengl, gdi

I have four windows, which are one parent window and three child windows. I want to make two of those child windows to draw stuff. The first child window is using OpenGL, and the second child window is using GDI. If I just draw some stuff on my OpenGL window and everything works fine, but when I try to draw(or just try to process WM_PAINT message) something else on my GDI window, those child windows become weird. Firstly, some parts(like buttons, statics, title bar) of my third child window will be missing. Secondly, if I try to resize any of those windows, one or two child windows will be missing. But once I click those windows they will be back. Thirdly, PeekMessage does not work anymore, it always return a FALSE, MessageBox seems not to work properly(I cannot see the popup window, but I can hear the sound), either.

My third child window just created.
[image]

After I click it.
[image]

I thought there might be something wrong with the message processing, but I cannot figure out what is actually happening. Is here anyone has any suggestions?

Message Loop:

```
MSG msg;


DWORD dwLast;
DWORD dwCurrent;
DWORD dwInterval = 20;//50 FPS 1000 / 50
dwLast = GetTickCount();

while (1) {

    while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE) == FALSE)
    {
        dwCurrent = GetTickCount();
        if (dwCurrent - dwLast < dwInterval)
            continue;

        SendMessage(Handle_Child_Demo, WM_PAINT, 0, 0);

        dwLast = dwCurrent;
    }
    if (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) != TRUE) {
        break;
    }
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

I am not using MDI to create my child windows, I just used CreateWindow to create all my child windows, and I think that must be something wrong with it, what else do I need to do to make sure those child windows work properly?

Comment: different window is different thread ... So you have to have separate OpenGL context for each GL window and use `wglMakeCurrent` to switch between contexts properly (on Activate and on Exit events). Also GDI and visual WinAPI calls MUST BE CALLED FROM MAIN THREAD OF TARGETED WINDOW (WndProc) otherwise weird things will happen even in unrelated code ... like random exception gfx errors crashes ... BTW you can combine GDI and GL in the same window without any problems ... just make sure updates are not forcing repainting in the wrong time.

Comment: The real problems get started when you got older Intel gfx cards/drivers see [What is the proper OpenGL initialisation on Intel HD 3000?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19099162/2521214)

Comment: I have only one GL window, and the whole program is using only one  thread. I use wglMakeCurrent(DC,GL) when it starts drawing, and use wglMakeCurrent(NULL,NULL) when it stopped.

Comment: @Spektre BTW I am not using Intel gfx cards.

Comment: You got 4 windows each call to its own WndProc callback you can consider as separate thread. If you access GDI or winapi calls between windows then you got a problem.

Comment: You mean I have to use wglMakeCurrent in every WndProc? Or I just use it when it is the GL window?

Comment: Only for GL windows ... on enter you have to set actual renedring context handle and on exit/close you should set it to NULL. Your problems could also be wrongly handled resize and repaint events ...

Comment: I just cannot understand why everything works fine without adding a handler to WM_PAINT for GDI window, and my only GL window resize code here 
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height); 
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);  
 glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
 glLoadIdentity();
 gluPerspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
 glLoadIdentity();

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Show the message loop for main window (that's usually in `WinMain` with `GetMessage/PeekMessage`). Also show the message loop for other OpenGL windows if any.

Comment: You can see the main window loop(the only one message loop) in my question now.

Comment: I am not using MDI to create my child windows, I just used CreateWindow to create all my child windows, and I think that must be something wrong with it, what else do I need to do to make sure those child windows work properly?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

MUST USE MDI to create child windows, just remember, USE MDI!!!! Or there will be something really weird, this is bacese those messages are not processed properly, and MDI will help us to do it.