# glewInit fails when called from a background thread

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

In my application, I have a hidden GLFW window that I am using for offscreen rendering. I want to use this window for rendering from several background threads. It's guaranteed that only one thread is using the window at a time.

Before each rendering operation on background thread I do the following:

```
glfwMakeContextCurrent((GLFWwindow *)window);
glewExperimental = withGlewExperimental ? GL_TRUE : GL_FALSE;
const auto glewInitStatus = glewInit();
if (glewInitStatus != GLEW_OK)
    LOG(ERROR) << "Could not initialize glew, error: " << glewGetErrorString(glewInitStatus);
```

First time, this executes normally, but when the second thread acquires the context the `glewInit` fails.

```
Could not initialize glew, error: Missing GL version
```

This does not seem to reproduce when I create a new hidden window for each thread, but `GLFW` prohibits the creation of windows outside of the main thread, and maintaining the pool of windows for each thread complicates the implementation and creates a lot of unnecessary windows. That's why I wanted all threads to render to the same window.

There is a thing called `GLEW_MX` which supports multiple contexts, but it only existed in old versions of `GLEW`, before `2.0.0`, and my version of `GLEW` does not have this option.

So, I would like to know the answers to the following questions:

1. Is this idea viable at all (rendering to a single window from multiple threads)?
2. If that is the case, how do I fix the error with `GLEW`
3. If it's not the case, what would you suggest as a workaround?

Comment: just a guess but Your description reminds me of this Intel driver bug [What is the proper OpenGL initialisation on Intel HD 3000?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19099162/2521214)

Comment: Dear close-voters, could you please explain how is this off-topic? I am so confused, what is on-topic then on Stackoverflow? Seems to me like a legit general programming/software development question.

Comment: @Spektre thank you for suggestion, but I think that's not the case; I am not creating multiple contexts in the same app, rather I use a single context from multiple threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Is this idea viable at all (rendering to a single window from multiple threads)?

The *Technically Correct* answer is yes.

The *Practically Correct* answer is no.

OpenGL is designed for use with a single thread per context. Virtually nothing about its API will behave correctly if you try to use more than one thread at the same time, and while it's fully possible to make OpenGL behave itself by passing context ownership from thread-to-thread, ensuring that in a multithreaded scenario, only one thread interacts with the context at once, I cannot conceive of a scenario where you'd actually make significant performance gains by doing so.

Generally speaking, the way that I handle multithreaded rendering is by building a Message Queue that multiple threads can write to, but only the rendering thread can read + execute from.

```
class Renderer {
    //Roll your own or find a good implementation somewhere online
    concurrent::queue<std::function<void()>> rendering_queue; 
    std::thread rendering_thread;
    GLFWwindow * window;
    /*...*/
public:
    Renderer(GLFWwindow * window) : window(window) {
        rendering_thread = std::thread([this]{
            glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
            glewInit(); //Check for error if necessary
            while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
                draw();
                glfwSwapBuffers(window);
            }
        });
    }

    Renderer(Renderer const&) = delete;

    ~Renderer() noexcept {
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GLFW_TRUE);
        rendering_thread.join();
    }

    void push_task(std::function<void()> func) {
        rendering_queue.push(std::move(func));
    }

    void draw() {
        std::function<void()> func;
        while(rendering_queue.try_pop(func)) func();
        /*Normal Rendering Tasks*/
    }
};

int main() {
    glfwInit();
    GLFWwindow * window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Hello World!", nullptr, nullptr);
    Renderer renderer(window);

    std::thread circle_drawer{[&renderer]{
        renderer.push_task([]{/*Draw a Circle*/});
        renderer.push_task([]{/*Draw a Circle*/});
        renderer.push_task([]{/*Draw a Circle*/});
        renderer.push_task([]{/*Draw a Circle*/});
        renderer.push_task([]{/*Draw a Circle*/});
        renderer.push_task([]{/*Draw a Circle*/});
        renderer.push_task([]{/*Draw a Circle*/});
        renderer.push_task([]{/*Draw a Circle*/});
        renderer.push_task([]{/*Draw a Circle*/});
    }};
    circle_drawer.detach();

    std::thread square_drawer{[&renderer]{
        renderer.push_task([]{/*Draw a Square*/});
        renderer.push_task([]{/*Draw a Square*/});
        renderer.push_task([]{/*Draw a Square*/});
        renderer.push_task([]{/*Draw a Square*/});
    }};
    square_drawer.detach();

    /*Etc...*/

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}
```

Obviously I'm abstracting away a lot of details, but that's mainly because your problem is pretty broad. This model should apply and be malleable for most applications that require, at least on a superficial level, the ability to multithread the rendering.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. I rewrote the app so that I never use a single context from multiple threads, and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you don’t need `glewInit` for each tread. AFAIK you only need to call it once per application.

I have never tried that, but I think you need workflow like this.

1. First thread: create window, `glewInit`, other openGL code to initialize rendering & render your stuff, `wglMakeCurrent( NULL, NULL )` when done.
2. Other thread: `wglMakeCurrent( dc, glrc )`, other openGL code to render your stuff, `wglMakeCurrent( NULL, NULL )` when done.

Just make sure you never use your OpenGL context or that Window’ HDC on different threads *at the same time*.

How good the idea is… I don’t like it too much. User-mode parts of OpenGL and GPU driver are huge, L1-L2 caches are per-core, and L3 cache becomes ~2 times slower when a cache line is shared between cores.

As you see, you can only use the GL context + Window’s HDC from one thread at the same time.

If I were designing that kind of stuff, I’d created a dedicated offscreen rendering thread. And implement a job queue for rendering jobs.

If you want these other threads to sleep waiting for job result, one simple method is `SendMessage` WinAPI with a custom window message, passing a pointer to a job in the message argument[s]. Rendering thread needs Windows message pump anyway.

If however you want your other threads to poll for rendering result, you can use `PostMessage` for submitting jobs, and e.g. ( `std::queue` guarded by critical section ) per thread for polling results.