# which shader stage is more effitient for matrix transformation

Tags: performance, glsl, shader, matrix-multiplication

I have 2 questions about the glsl efficiency.

1. In the fully user-defined shader pipeline

   > vs -> tcs -> tes -> gs -> fs

   the first 4 stages are able to be used for the operation like this:

   ```
   gl_Position = MPV_matrices * vec4(in_pos, 1);
   ```

   Which stage is more efficient for this? Is it hardware or version dependent?
2. Many tutorials about using **GLSL** are showing examples which are passing a vertex position between the shaders instead of using in-built variable `gl_Position` only.

   Does it make sense in terms of efficiency?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Such Transforms are commonly used in VS**

   That is because geometry and teselation is not usually used for basic shaders. And in Fragment it would mean that you need to multiply on per fragment basis which is much much more occurent than in per vertex hence performance drops... So people are used to place such transforms into VS and do not think about it too much.
2. **custom input/output variables**

   We sometimes need vertexes in more than one coordinate system and it is usually faster to use inbuild interpolators than transform on per fragment basis.

   For example I sometimes need 3 coordinate systems at once (screen, world, TBN) for proper computations in FS.

   Another thing to consider is accuracy see:

   - [How to correctly linearize depth in OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42515399/2521214)
   - [ray and ellipsoid intersection accuracy improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25470493/2521214)

Comment: Your reasoning is completely off, you can't write nor read `gl_Position` in fragment shader stage, `gl_Position` is used by the fixed function stages(primitive assembly, clipping, culling and rasterization) happening *before* (and **possibly** leading to) fragment shader execution. Regarding "efficiency" on modern GPUs, from a *hardware* point of view there's no inherent difference between e.g. doing things in a vertex vs a fragment shader apart from the obvious consideration of doing things per vertex vs doing them per fragment.