# Linear depth buffer

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, depth-buffer

Many people use usual perspective matrix with third line like this:

```
(0  0  (n+f)/(n-f) 2*n*f/(n-f))
```

But it has problem with float precision near far clipping surface. The result is z-fighting.
What about to use linear transformation of z? Let's change the matrix third line to this:

```
(0  0  -2/(f-n) (-f-n)/(f-n))
```

It will be linear transformation z from [-n, -f] to [-1, 1]. Then, we will add the line in vertex shader:

```
gl_Position.z *= gl_Position.w;
```

After perspective divide the z value will be restored.

Why don't it used everywhere? I found a lot of articles in internet. All of them used a usual matrix. 
Is linear transformation described by me has problems what I don't see?

**Update**: This is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42509883/how-to-correctly-linearize-depth-in-opengl-es-in-ios). My question is not about how to do linear depth buffer. In my case, the buffer is already linear. I don't understand, why is this method not used? Are there traps in the inner webgl pipeline?

Comment: if you see the duplicate I linked it should answer your questions. In case you did not see it: If you linearize values in fragment then you lose precision as you got already rounded values. The idea is to store linearized values to the Z-buffer instead of linearize them after storing. This way you circumvent the perspective division and all is well...  Linear Z-buffer is used only for large Depth view. For smaller ones is better use the OpenGL non linear one as it has visually the same resolution of depth.

Comment: @Spektre: This question is not a duplicate of the question you linked (in my opinion), so I re-opened it. While both questions relate to a linear depth buffer, this question here specifically asks about  linearizing depth by modifying clip space z in the vertex shader (which can't be done), while the linked question (correctly) linearizes z at the per-fragment level.

Comment: @derhass OK btw +1 for the answer those accuracy graphs are nice

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The approach you're describing simply doesn't work. One advantage of a hyperbolic Z buffer is that we can interpolate the resulting depth values *linearly* in screen space. If you multiply `gl_Position.z` by `gl_Position.w`, the resulting z value will not be linear in screen space any more, but the depth test will still use linearly interpolated values. This results in your primitives becoming bend in the z-dimension, leading to completely wrong occlusions and intersections between nearby primitives (especially if the vertices of on primitive lie near the center of the other).

The only way to use a linear depth buffer is to actually do the non-linear interpolation for the Z value yourself in the fragment shader. This can be done (and boil's down to just linearly transform the perspective-corrected interpolated w value for each fragment, hence it is sometimes called "W buffering"), but you're losing the benefits of the early Z test and - much worse - of the hierarchical depth test.

An interesting way to improve the precision of the depth test is to use a floating point buffer in combination with a reversed Z projection matrix, as explained in this [Depth Precision Visualized blog article](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/depth-precision-visualized).

**UPDATE**

From your comment:

> Depth in screen space is linear interpolation of NDC, how I understand form here. In my case, it will be linear interpolation of linear interpolation of z from camera space. Thus, depth in screen space interpolated already.

You mis-understood this. May main point was that the linear interpolation in screen space is only valid *if* you're using Z values which are already hyperbolically distorted (like NDC Z). If you want to use eye-space Z, this can **not** be linearly interpolated. I made some drawings of the situation:

[image]

This is a top-down view on eye-space and NDC. All drawings are actually to scale. The green ray is a view ray going through some pixel. This pixel happens to be the one which directly represents the mid-point of that one triangle (green point).

After the projection matrix is applied and the division by `w` has happened, we are in normalized device coordinates. Note that the direction of the viewing ray is now just `+z`, and all view rays of all pixels became parallel (so that we can just ignore Z when rasterizing). Due to the hyperbolic relation of the z value, the green point now does not lie on exactly on the center any more, but is squeezed towards the far plane. However, the important point is that this point now lies on the straight line formed by the (hyperbolically distorted) end points of the primitive - hence we simply can interpolate `z_ndc` linearly in screen space.

If you use a linear depth buffer, the green point now lies at z in the center of the primitive again, but that point is not on the straight line - you actually bend your primitives.

Since the depth test will use a linear interpolation, it will just get the points as in the rightmost drawing as input from the vertex shader, but will interpolate them linearly - connecting those points by straight lines. As a result, the intersection between primitives will not be where it actually has to be.

Another way to think of this: Imagine you draw some primitive which extents into the z-dimension, with some perspective projection. Due to perspective, stuff that is farther away will appear smaller. So if you just go one pixel to the right in screen space, the z extent covered by that step will actually bigger if the primitive is far away, while it will become smaller and smaller as closer you get. So if you just go in equal-sized steps to the right, the z-steps you're making will vary depending on the orientation and position of your primitive. However, we want to use a linear interpolation, so we want to make the same z step size for every x step. The only we to do this is by distorting the space z is in - and the hyperbolical distortion introduced by the division by `w` exactly does that.

Comment: Depth in screen space is linear interpolation of NDC, how I understand form [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Viewport_transform). In my case, it will be linear interpolation of linear interpolation of z from camera space. Thus, depth in screen space interpolated already. Maybe, didn't I understand you?

Comment: I understood. Thank you very much.  And how I understood, if no crossing of triangles then no problems. Can you give link on any mathematical proving, what lines in camera space transform to lines in NDC, please? Just to be fully sure.

Comment: @lzv: "if no crossing of triangles then no problems". Nope, that is not true. Imagine a very large triangle, and a very small triangle which lies closely behind it, somehwhere near the center of the large triangle.  The small triangle can then appear in front of the large one if you just linearly interpolate eye-space z. What this is all about is perspective-correct interpolation (which becomes nonlinear except for primitives which are exactly parallel to the image plane).

Comment: You are right, I didn't think about it. I thought all triangles are approximately same size.  It may be special case. But in general they are not.

Answer (score 3):

We don't use a linear transformation because that will have precision problems *at all distances* equally. At least now, the precision problems only show up far away, where you're less likely to notice. A linear mapping spaces the error out evenly, which makes errors more likely to happen close to the camera.

Comment: I doubt linear mapping is that bad. AFAIK it's often considered a good thing, as in [the article](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/depth-precision-visualized) linked by @derhass (though it suggests a different way to achieve that).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: the article I linked does not achieve a linear mapping at all. It just explains how the hyperbolical mapping can be optimized for floating point formats, by just using the property that the representable floats get denser and denser as you get closer to zero.

Comment: @derhass Poor choice of words on my side. I should've said linear distribution of precision, which is why OP considers linear mapping.