# Trying to get 3d point from 2d click on screen with openGL

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl, glreadpixels

i have a PyOpenGL project. i render a stadium and some pcd clouds. and i want to extract a point from the screen. i have the X,Y values and i am trying to use `gluUnProject` or `glReadPixelsf` to get the point in x,y,z.

but i am getting weird numbers 
for example: 
i ZOOMED as much as i can to the 0,0,0 point with my camera and used the

```
 worldCoordinate1 = gluUnProject(x, realy, 0.0, mvmatrix, projmatrix, vport)
```

gets :

```
(-79.71705354658924, 3.024572101740394, -1.8905707759570176)
```

which looks fine. this is truly the camera location. 
but my problem starts with the far plane.

```
worldCoordinate2 = gluUnProject(x, realy, 1.0, mvmatrix, projmatrix, vport)
```

ideally i want this to get me the point colliding with any buffer object drawn. but i am getting

```
  (2098.1759117202328, -121.52711517535181, 77.12367509703613)
```

my function looks like this:

```
def get_clicked_location(x, y):
    vport = glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT)
    mvmatrix = glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
    projmatrix = glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX)
    realy = vport[3] - y
    worldCoordinate1 = gluUnProject(x, realy, 0.0, mvmatrix, projmatrix, vport)
    worldCoordinate2 = gluUnProject(x, realy, 1.0, mvmatrix, projmatrix, vport)
    print worldCoordinate1
    print worldCoordinate2
    data = glReadPixelsf(x, realy, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)
    pick = map(ord, data)
    print pick
```

what i want is to get the x,y,z point colliding with the buffer drawn on screen. but i cant seem to find the way. also i found some people using glreadpixelsf but i don't think i understand how to combine them thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`glReadPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml) to read the depth from the depth buffer of the default framebuffer. Use the format `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT` to do so:

```py
depth = glReadPixels(x, realy, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT)
```

This depth can be used with [`gluUnProject`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluUnProject.xml), to find the world (or model) coordinate of the fragment:

```py
vport      = glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT)
mvmatrix   = glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
projmatrix = glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX)

worldCoordinate1 = gluUnProject(x, realy, depth, mvmatrix, projmatrix, vport)
```

See also [get 3d point in space using 2d point in image in python opengl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434826/get-3d-point-in-space-using-2d-point-in-image-in-python-opengl/50435080#50435080)

Comment: i just forgot to use glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) 
it works perfectly now! thank you so much!