# GLUT torus colliding with camera

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, collision-detection, glut

I want to implement collision of 6 torus which are randomly disturbed in the game area. It is a simple 3D space game using the perspective view and in first person. I saw some stack overflow answer suggesting to compute distance of whatever (player) to torus cell and if bigger than half or whole cell size you are colliding +/- your coordinate system and map topology tweaks. But if we take the distance that means we're only considering the z co-ordinates so if the camera moved to that distance (without considering x,y coordinates) it's always taking as a collision which is wrong right?

I'm hoping to do this using AABB algorithm. Is it ok to consider camera position and torus position as 2 boxes and check the collision (box to box collision) or camera as a point and torus as a box (point to box)? Or can somebody suggest best way to do that?

Below is the code that I've tried so far.

```
float im[16], m[16], znear = 0.1, zfar = 100.0, fovx = 45.0 * M_PI / 180.0;
glm::vec3 p0, p1, p2, p3, o, u, v;

//p0, p1, p2, p3 holds your znear camera screen corners in world coordinates 
void ChangeSize(int w, int h)
{
    GLfloat fAspect;
    
    // Prevent a divide by zero
    if(h == 0)
        h = 1;
    
    // Set Viewport to window dimensions
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    
    // Calculate aspect ratio of the window
    fAspect = (GLfloat)w*1.0/(GLfloat)h;
    
    // Set the perspective coordinate system
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    
    // field of view of 45 degrees, near and far planes 1.0 and 1000
    //that znear and zfar should typically have a ratio of 1000:1 to make sorting out z depth easier for the GPU
    gluPerspective(45.0f, fAspect, 0.1f, 300.0f);  //may need to make larger depending on project
    // Modelview matrix reset
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // get camera matrix (must be in right place in code before model transformations)
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, im);    // get camera inverse matrix
    matrix_inv(m, im);                   // m = inverse(im)
    u = glm::vec3(m[0], m[1], m[2]);         // x axis
    v = glm::vec3(m[4], m[5], m[6]);         // y axis
    o = glm::vec3(m[12], m[13], m[14]);         // origin
    o -= glm::vec3(m[8], m[9], m[10]) * znear;   // z axis offset
    // scale by FOV
    u *= znear * tan(0.5 * fovx);
    v *= znear * tan(0.5 * fovx / fAspect);
    // get rectangle coorners
    p0 = o - u - v;
    p1 = o + u - v;
    p2 = o + u + v;
    p3 = o - u + v;

}



void matrix_inv(float* a, float* b) // a[16] = Inverse(b[16])
{
    float x, y, z;
    // transpose of rotation matrix
    a[0] = b[0];
    a[5] = b[5];
    a[10] = b[10];
    x = b[1]; a[1] = b[4]; a[4] = x;
    x = b[2]; a[2] = b[8]; a[8] = x;
    x = b[6]; a[6] = b[9]; a[9] = x;
    // copy projection part
    a[3] = b[3];
    a[7] = b[7];
    a[11] = b[11];
    a[15] = b[15];
    // convert origin: new_pos = - new_rotation_matrix * old_pos
    x = (a[0] * b[12]) + (a[4] * b[13]) + (a[8] * b[14]);
    y = (a[1] * b[12]) + (a[5] * b[13]) + (a[9] * b[14]);
    z = (a[2] * b[12]) + (a[6] * b[13]) + (a[10] * b[14]);
    a[12] = -x;
    a[13] = -y;
    a[14] = -z;
}

//Store torus coordinates
std::vector<std::vector<GLfloat>> translateTorus = { { 0.0, 1.0, -10.0, 1 },   { 0.0, 4.0, -6.0, 1 } , { -1.0, 0.0, -4.0, 1 },
{ 3.0, 1.0, -6.0, 1 }, { 1.0, -1.0, -9.0, 1 } , { 4.0, 1.0, -4.0, 1 } };

GLfloat xpos, ypos, zpos, flagToDisplayCrystal;
//Looping through 6 Torus
    for (int i = 0; i < translateTorus.size(); i++) {
        //Get the torus coordinates
        xpos = translateTorus[i][0];
        ypos = translateTorus[i][1];
        zpos = translateTorus[i][2];
        //This variable will work as a variable to display crystal after collision
        flagToDisplayCrystal = translateTorus[i][3];

        //p0 min, p2 max

        //Creating a square using Torus index coordinates and radius
        double halfside = 1.0 / 2;

//This (xpos+halfside), (xpos-halfside), (ypos+halfside), (ypos-halfside) are //created using Torus index and radius

        float d1x = p0[0] - (xpos + halfside);
        float d1y = p0[1] - (ypos + halfside);
        float d2x = (xpos - halfside) - p2[0];
        float d2y = (ypos - halfside) - p2[1];

    
        //Collision is checking here
        //For square's min z and max z is checking whether equal to camera's min //z and max z
        if ((d1x > 0.0f || d1y > 0.0f || d2x > 0.0f || d2y > 0.0f) && p2[2] == zpos && p0[2] == zpos) {
            //If there is collision update the variable as 0
            translateTorus[i][3] = 0;

        }
        else {

            if (flagToDisplayCrystal == 1) {

                glPushMatrix();
                glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
                glTranslatef(xpos, ypos, zpos);
                glRotatef(fPlanetRot, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
                glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

                // Select the texture object
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[3]);

                glutSolidTorus(0.1, 1.0, 30, 30);
                glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
                glPopMatrix();

            }
        }
}
```

[image: These are 3 Torus]

Comment: you want collision between torus and what? point/camera?  collisions can be computed outside GPU on the scene/world data without any rendering or camera. In case of torus I would use cylinder (defined by its axis and radius) instead of AABB. All the computations depends between what you want to collide (AABB,point, sphere ...)  If you want to use rendering (collision with camera) then its possible too but not that easy as you need to render index buffer of objects and then reading each pixel of screen and testing if it belongs to torus and if its close enough... So which one it is?

Comment: Hi @Spektre I want to check the collision between torus and camera. When torus hits the camera player's scores will be incremented by one. So we have to navigate to all the torus in order to win the game. Like that the game is working.

Comment: @Spektre Open GL using GLUT library

Comment: I mean using `glBegin/glEnd` or VBO/VAO and with or without shaders ? GLUT is support lib for GL

Comment: @Spektre it's glBegin/glEnd without shaders

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218137/discussion-between-rasanga-abeykoon-and-spektre).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I mentioned in the comments you got 2 options either use OpenGL rendering or compute entirely on CPU side without it. Let start with rendering first:

1. **render your scene**

   but instead of color of torus and stuff use integer indexes (for example 0 empty space, 1 obstacle, 2 torus ...) you can even have separate indexes for each object in the world so you know exactly which one is hit etc ...

   so: clear screen with empty color, render your scene (using indexes instead of color with `glColor??(???)`) without lighting or shading or whatever. But **Do not swap buffers !!!** as that would show the stuff on screen and cause flickering.
2. **read rendered screen and depth buffers**

   you simply use `glReadPixels` to copy your screen and depth buffers into CPU side memory (1D arrays) lets call them `scr[],zed[]`.
3. **scan the `scr[]` for color matching torus indexes**

   simply loop through all pixels and if torus pixel found check its depth. If it is close enough to camera you found your collision.
4. **render normally**

   now clear screen again and render your screen with colors and lighting... now you can swap buffers too.

Beware depth buffer will be non linear which requires linearization to obtain original depth in world units. For more about it and example of reading both `scr,zed` see:

- [depth buffer got by glReadPixels is always 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51130948/2521214)
- [OpenGL 3D-raypicking with high poly meshes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51764105/2521214)

The other approach is is much faster in case you have not too many torus'es. You simply compute intersection between camera znear plane and torus. Which boils down to either AABB vs rectangle intersection or cylinder vs. rectangle intersection.

However if you not familiar with 3D vector math you might get lost quickly.

let assume the torus is described by AABB. Then intersection between that and rectangle boils down to checking intersection between line (each edge of AABB) and rectangle. So simply finding instersection between plane and line and checking if the point is inside rectangle.

if our rectangle is defined by its vertexes in CW or CCW order `(p0,p1,p2,p3)` and line by endpoints `q0,q1` then:

```
n = normalize(cross(p1-p0,p2-p1)) // is rectangle normal
dq = normalize(q1-q0)             // is line direction
q = q0 + dq*dot(dq,p1-p0)         // is plane/line intersection
```

So now just check if `q` is inside rectangle. There are 2 ways either test if all crosses between `q-edge_start` and `edge_end-edge_start` have the same direction or all dots between all `edge_normal` and `q-edge_point` has the same sign or zero.

The problem is that both AABB and rectangle must be in the same coordinate system so either transform AABB into camera coordinates by using modelview matrix or transform the rectangle into world coordinates using inverse of modelview. The latter is better as you do it just once instead of transforming each torus'es AABB ...

For more info about math side see:

- [Cone to box collision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62257945/2521214)
- [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)

The rectangle itself is just extracted from your camera matrix (part of modelviev)  position, and x,y basis vectors gives you the "center" and axises of your rectangle... The size must be derived from the perspective matrix (or parameters you passed to it especially aspect ratio, FOV and znear)

Well first you need to obtain camera (view) matrix. The `GL_MODELVIEW` usually holds:

```
GL_MODELVIEW = Inverse(Camera)*Rendered_Object
```

so you need to find the place in your code where your `GL_MODELVIEW` holds just the `Inverse(Camera)` transformation and there place:

```
        float aspect=float(xs)/float(ys);   // aspect from OpenGL window resolution
        float im[16],m[16],znear=0.1,zfar=100.0,fovx=60.0*M_PI/180.0;
        vec3 p0,p1,p2,p3,o,u,v;             // 3D vectors
        // this is how my perspective is set
//      glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
//      glLoadIdentity();
//      gluPerspective(fovx*180.0/(M_PI*aspect),aspect,znear,zfar);
        // get camera matrix (must be in right place in code before model transformations)
        glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,im);    // get camera inverse matrix
        matrix_inv(m,im);                   // m = inverse(im)
        u =vec3(m[ 0],m[ 1],m[ 2]);         // x axis
        v =vec3(m[ 4],m[ 5],m[ 6]);         // y axis
        o =vec3(m[12],m[13],m[14]);         // origin
        o-=vec3(m[ 8],m[ 9],m[10])*znear;   // z axis offset
        // scale by FOV
        u*=znear*tan(0.5*fovx);
        v*=znear*tan(0.5*fovx/aspect);
        // get rectangle coorners
        p0=o-u-v;
        p1=o+u-v;
        p2=o+u+v;
        p3=o-u+v;
        // render it for debug
        glColor3f(1.0,1.0,0.0);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0); glVertex3fv(p0.dat);
        glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0); glVertex3fv(p1.dat);
        glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0); glVertex3fv(p2.dat);
        glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0); glVertex3fv(p3.dat);
        glEnd();
```

Which basicaly loads the matrix into CPU side variables inverse it like this:

```
void matrix_inv(float *a,float *b) // a[16] = Inverse(b[16])
    {
    float x,y,z;
    // transpose of rotation matrix
    a[ 0]=b[ 0];
    a[ 5]=b[ 5];
    a[10]=b[10];
    x=b[1]; a[1]=b[4]; a[4]=x;
    x=b[2]; a[2]=b[8]; a[8]=x;
    x=b[6]; a[6]=b[9]; a[9]=x;
    // copy projection part
    a[ 3]=b[ 3];
    a[ 7]=b[ 7];
    a[11]=b[11];
    a[15]=b[15];
    // convert origin: new_pos = - new_rotation_matrix * old_pos
    x=(a[ 0]*b[12])+(a[ 4]*b[13])+(a[ 8]*b[14]);
    y=(a[ 1]*b[12])+(a[ 5]*b[13])+(a[ 9]*b[14]);
    z=(a[ 2]*b[12])+(a[ 6]*b[13])+(a[10]*b[14]);
    a[12]=-x;
    a[13]=-y;
    a[14]=-z;
    }
```

And compute the corners with perspective in mind as described above...

I used GLSL like `vec3` but you can use any 3D math even own like `float p0[3],...`. You just need `+,-` and multiplying by constant.

Now the `p0,p1,p2,p3` holds your znear camera screen corners in world coordinates.

**[Edit1] example**

I managed to put together simple example for this. Here support functiosn used first:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void glutSolidTorus(float r,float R,int na,int nb) // render torus(r,R)
    {
    float *pnt=new float[(na+1)*(nb+1)*3*2]; if (pnt==NULL) return;
    float *nor=pnt+((na+1)*(nb+1)*3);
    float ca,sa,cb,sb,a,b,da,db,x,y,z,nx,ny,nz;
    int ia,ib,i,j;
    da=2.0*M_PI/float(na);
    db=2.0*M_PI/float(nb);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    for (i=0,a=0.0,ia=0;ia<=na;ia++,a+=da){ ca=cos(a); sa=sin(a);
     for (   b=0.0,ib=0;ib<=nb;ib++,b+=db){ cb=cos(b); sb=sin(b);
        z=r*ca;
        x=(R+z)*cb; nx=(x-(R*cb))/r;
        y=(R+z)*sb; ny=(y-(R*sb))/r;
        z=r*sa;     nz=sa;
        pnt[i]=x; nor[i]=nx; i++;
        pnt[i]=y; nor[i]=ny; i++;
        pnt[i]=z; nor[i]=nz; i++;
        }}
    glEnd();
    for (ia=0;ia<na;ia++)
        {
        i=(ia+0)*(nb+1)*3;
        j=(ia+1)*(nb+1)*3;
        glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
        for (ib=0;ib<=nb;ib++)
            {
            glNormal3fv(nor+i); glVertex3fv(pnt+i); i+=3;
            glNormal3fv(nor+j); glVertex3fv(pnt+j); j+=3;
            }
        glEnd();
        }

    delete[] pnt;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const int AABB_lin[]=   // AABB lines
    {
    0,1,
    1,2,
    2,3,
    3,0,
    4,5,
    5,6,
    6,7,
    7,4,
    0,4,
    1,5,
    2,6,
    3,7,
    -1
    };
const int AABB_fac[]=   // AABB quads
    {
    3,2,1,0,
    4,5,6,7,
    0,1,5,4,
    1,2,6,5,
    2,3,7,6,
    3,0,4,7,
    -1
    };
void AABBSolidTorus(vec3 *aabb,float r,float R) // aabb[8] = AABB of torus(r,R)
    {
    R+=r;
    aabb[0]=vec3(-R,-R,-r);
    aabb[1]=vec3(+R,-R,-r);
    aabb[2]=vec3(+R,+R,-r);
    aabb[3]=vec3(-R,+R,-r);
    aabb[4]=vec3(-R,-R,+r);
    aabb[5]=vec3(+R,-R,+r);
    aabb[6]=vec3(+R,+R,+r);
    aabb[7]=vec3(-R,+R,+r);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void matrix_inv(float *a,float *b) // a[16] = Inverse(b[16])
    {
    float x,y,z;
    // transpose of rotation matrix
    a[ 0]=b[ 0];
    a[ 5]=b[ 5];
    a[10]=b[10];
    x=b[1]; a[1]=b[4]; a[4]=x;
    x=b[2]; a[2]=b[8]; a[8]=x;
    x=b[6]; a[6]=b[9]; a[9]=x;
    // copy projection part
    a[ 3]=b[ 3];
    a[ 7]=b[ 7];
    a[11]=b[11];
    a[15]=b[15];
    // convert origin: new_pos = - new_rotation_matrix * old_pos
    x=(a[ 0]*b[12])+(a[ 4]*b[13])+(a[ 8]*b[14]);
    y=(a[ 1]*b[12])+(a[ 5]*b[13])+(a[ 9]*b[14]);
    z=(a[ 2]*b[12])+(a[ 6]*b[13])+(a[10]*b[14]);
    a[12]=-x;
    a[13]=-y;
    a[14]=-z;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const int QUAD_lin[]=   // quad lines
    {
    0,1,
    1,2,
    2,3,
    3,0,
    -1
    };
const int QUAD_fac[]=   // quad quads
    {
    0,1,2,3,
    -1
    };
void get_perspective_znear(vec3 *quad) // quad[4] = world coordinates of 4 corners of screen at znear distance from camera
    {
    vec3 o,u,v;                                     // 3D vectors
    float im[16],m[16],znear,zfar,aspect,fovx;
    // get stuff from perspective
    glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX,m);            // get perspective projection matrix
    zfar =0.5*m[14]*(1.0-((m[10]-1.0)/(m[10]+1.0)));// compute zfar from perspective matrix
    znear=zfar*(m[10]+1.0)/(m[10]-1.0);             // compute znear from perspective matrix
    aspect=m[5]/m[0];
    fovx=2.0*atan(1.0/m[5])*aspect;
    // get stuff from camera matrix (must be in right place in code before model transformations)
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,im);            // get camera inverse matrix
    matrix_inv(m,im);                               // m = inverse(im)
    u =vec3(m[ 0],m[ 1],m[ 2]);                     // x axis
    v =vec3(m[ 4],m[ 5],m[ 6]);                     // y axis
    o =vec3(m[12],m[13],m[14]);                     // origin
    o-=vec3(m[ 8],m[ 9],m[10])*znear;               // z axis offset
    // scale by FOV
    u*=znear*tan(0.5*fovx);
    v*=znear*tan(0.5*fovx/aspect);
    // get rectangle coorners
    quad[0]=o-u-v;
    quad[1]=o+u-v;
    quad[2]=o+u+v;
    quad[3]=o-u+v;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool collideLineQuad(vec3 *lin,vec3 *quad)  // return if lin[2] is colliding quad[4]
    {
    float t,l,u,v;
    vec3 p,p0,p1,dp;
    vec3 U,V,W;
    // quad (rectangle) basis vectors
    U=quad[1]-quad[0]; u=length(U); u*=u;
    V=quad[3]-quad[0]; v=length(V); v*=v;
    W=normalize(cross(U,V));
    // convert line from world coordinates to quad local ones
    p0=lin[0]-quad[0]; p0=vec3(dot(p0,U)/u,dot(p0,V)/v,dot(p0,W));
    p1=lin[1]-quad[0]; p1=vec3(dot(p1,U)/u,dot(p1,V)/v,dot(p1,W));
    dp=p1-p0;
    // test if crossing the plane
    if (fabs(dp.z)<1e-10) return false;
    t=-p0.z/dp.z;
    p=p0+(t*dp);
    // test inside 2D quad (rectangle)
    if ((p.x<0.0)||(p.x>1.0)) return false;
    if ((p.y<0.0)||(p.y>1.0)) return false;
    // inside line
    if ((t<0.0)||(t>1.0)) return false;
    return true;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool collideQuadQuad(vec3 *quad0,vec3 *quad1)   // return if quad0[4] is colliding quad1[4]
    {
    int i;
    vec3 l[2];
    // lines vs. quads
    for (i=0;QUAD_lin[i]>=0;)
        {
        l[0]=quad0[QUAD_lin[i]]; i++;
        l[1]=quad0[QUAD_lin[i]]; i++;
        if (collideLineQuad(l,quad1)) return true;
        }
    for (i=0;QUAD_lin[i]>=0;)
        {
        l[0]=quad1[QUAD_lin[i]]; i++;
        l[1]=quad1[QUAD_lin[i]]; i++;
        if (collideLineQuad(l,quad0)) return true;
        }
    // ToDo coplanar quads tests (not needed for AABB test)
    return false;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool collideAABBQuad(vec3 *aabb,vec3 *quad) // return if aabb[8] is colliding quad[4]
    {
    int i;
    vec3 q[4],n,p;
    // test all AABB faces (rectangle) for intersection with quad (rectangle)
    for (i=0;AABB_fac[i]>=0;)
        {
        q[0]=aabb[AABB_fac[i]]; i++;
        q[1]=aabb[AABB_fac[i]]; i++;
        q[2]=aabb[AABB_fac[i]]; i++;
        q[3]=aabb[AABB_fac[i]]; i++;
        if (collideQuadQuad(q,quad)) return true;
        }
    // test if one point of quad is fully inside AABB
    for (i=0;AABB_fac[i]>=0;i+=4)
        {
        n=cross(aabb[AABB_fac[i+1]]-aabb[AABB_fac[i+0]],
                aabb[AABB_fac[i+2]]-aabb[AABB_fac[i+1]]);
        if (dot(n,quad[0]-aabb[AABB_fac[i+0]])>0.0) return false;
        }
    return true;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And here the usage (during rendering):

```cpp
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    int i;
    float m[16];
    mat4 m0,m1;
    vec4 v4;

    float aspect=float(xs)/float(ys);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60.0/aspect,aspect,0.1,20.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    static float anim=180.0; anim+=0.1; if (anim>=360.0) anim-=360.0;

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    vec3 line[2],quad[4],aabb[8];   // 3D vectors
    get_perspective_znear(quad);

    // store view matrix for latter
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,m);
    m0=mat4(m[0],m[1],m[2],m[3],m[4],m[5],m[6],m[7],m[8],m[9],m[10],m[11],m[12],m[13],m[14],m[15]);
    m0=inverse(m0);
    // <<-- here should be for start that loop through your toruses
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();

    // set/animate torus position
    glTranslatef(0.3,0.3,3.5*(-1.0-cos(anim)));
    glRotatef(+75.0,0.5,0.5,0.0);
    // get actual matrix and convert it to the change
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,m);
    m1=m0*mat4(m[0],m[1],m[2],m[3],m[4],m[5],m[6],m[7],m[8],m[9],m[10],m[11],m[12],m[13],m[14],m[15]);
    // render torus and compute its AABB
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glutSolidTorus(0.1,0.5,36,36);
    AABBSolidTorus(aabb,0.1,0.5);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

    // convert AABB to the same coordinates as quad
    for (i=0;i<8;i++) aabb[i]=(m1*vec4(aabb[i],1.0)).xyz;
    // restore original view matrix
    glPopMatrix();

    // render wireframe AABB
    glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    for (i=0;AABB_lin[i]>=0;i++)
     glVertex3fv(aabb[AABB_lin[i]].dat);
    glEnd();
/*
    // render filled AABB for debug
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    for (i=0;AABB_fac[i]>=0;i++)
     glVertex3fv(aabb[AABB_fac[i]].dat);
    glEnd();

    // render quad for debug
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    for (i=0;QUAD_fac[i]>=0;i++)
     glVertex3fv(quad[QUAD_fac[i]].dat);
    glEnd();
*/
    // render X on colision
    if (collideAABBQuad(aabb,quad))
        {
        glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3fv(quad[0].dat);
        glVertex3fv(quad[2].dat);
        glVertex3fv(quad[1].dat);
        glVertex3fv(quad[3].dat);
        glEnd();
        }

    // <<-- here should be end of the for that loop through your toruses

    glFlush();
    SwapBuffers(hdc);
```

just ignore the GLUT solid torus function as you already got it ... Here preview:

[image: preview]

The red cross indicates collision with screen ...

Comment: Hi @Spektre +1 and thanks for your answer. can u please plain how to extract rectangle from camera metrix. fAspect=800*0.1/600   gluPerspective(45.0f, fAspect, 0.1f, 300.0f);                             gluLookAt(x, y, z,
  x + lx, y + ly, z + lz,
  upX, upY, 0.0f); Using these values

Comment: Another thing when we create rectangle using camera coordinates we are not considering z axis because you are suggesting to create rectangle. why don't we consider z coordinates?

Comment: @RasangaAbeykoon no z coordinates are not ignored I added stuff to my answer...

Comment: thank you very much for your code so if the  camera is moving forward or backward znear can be changed right. So we need to change the znear of above code right? Then how do we get the new znear. Please can u explain that part also

Comment: @RasangaAbeykoon no `znear` is the focal length of perspective camera (distance between focus and "screen")  and its constant... if you move your camera/view using `glTranslate` then the change is reflected in the `GL_MODELVIEW` at elements `12,13,14` the `znear` does not change at all... its the number you pass to `gluPerspective` or whatever function you use to set up the perspective matrix for `GL_PROJECTION`

Comment: Hi @Spektre  can u tell me upper left corner coordinates of camera? is it p3? and height and width of the camera?

Comment: @RasangaAbeykoon yep exactly `p3` is upper left corner of the screen at `znear` distance from camera focus ... the half-height and half-width are the sizes of u,v vectors.

Comment: Hi @Spektre please can u show full code of 1 torus colliding with the camera. If u want I'll send my code to u. I tried as u suggested and it's not identifying collision

Comment: @RasangaAbeykoon add your relevant code to your question ... so I do not need to do everything from scratch ...

Comment: Hi @Spektre I've updated the question with what I've tried so far. I followed AABB collision and took the camera also as a AABB. I applied 2d AABB collision and checked the z coordinates of camera and torus's AABB is similar then assumed there's a collision.

Comment: I do not use GLUT... How is  the torus oriented (on XY plane?)? also inner radius is from center of torus or its the radius of the bended tube? the outter radius is outter or its the radius of bended tube center circle?

Comment: using these glTranslatef(xpos, ypos, zpos); torus is oriented in x, y, z plane. xpos, ypos, zpos, collisionStatus are taking from hardcoded array.           std::vector<std::vector<GLfloat>> translateTorus = { { 0.0, 1.0, -10.0, 1 },   { 0.0, 4.0, -6.0, 1 } , { -1.0, 0.0, -4.0, 1 },
{ 3.0, 1.0, -6.0, 1 }, { 1.0, -1.0, -9.0, 1 } , { 4.0, 1.0, -4.0, 1 } }; I'm creating that square from outer radius of torus.

Comment: @RasangaAbeykoon that was obvious... but the torus tube center circle is at XY or YZ or ZX plane (I am guessin XY)? and the radiuses are which ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218338/discussion-between-rasanga-abeykoon-and-spektre).

Comment: @RasangaAbeykoon added edit1 with example... it works for any orientation of torus not just axis aligned one ...